# Child component does not get state from parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have the following code, in App.js;

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        isLoggedIn: false,
        username: "",
    }
}

componentDidMount() {
    let isLoggedIn = false;
    let username = "";

    if (localStorage.getItem("token")) {
        fetch("https://localhost:8000/user", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Authorization": `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("token")}`
            }
        }).then(response => response.json()).then(response => {
            if (response.success) {
                isLoggedIn = true;
                username = response.username;
            } else {
                isLoggedIn = false;
                username = "";
                localStorage.removeItem("token");
            }

            this.setState({
                isLoggedIn : isLoggedIn,
                username: username
            })
        })
    }
}

render() {

    return (
       <Navbar username={this.state.username}/>
    )
}
```

By console logging the output, once componentDidMount is called the username in state is assigned as it should be. In Navbar.js;

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        navComponents: []
    }
}

componentDidMount()  {
    console.log(this.props.username);
    let navComponents = [];
    if (this.props.username === "") { //Not Signed In.
        navComponents.push(
            <ul className="Navbar-list">
                <li className="Navbar-item">
                    <Link to="/register" className="Navbar-link">Sign Up</Link>
                </li>
                <li className="Navbar-item">
                    <Link to="/login" className="Navbar-link">Log In</Link>
                </li>
            </ul>
        );
    } else {
        navComponents.push(
            <p>Hello, {this.props.username}</p>
        )
        navComponents.push(
            <ul className="Navbar-item">
                <Link to="/signout" className="Navbar-link">Sign Out</Link>
            </ul>
        )
    }
    this.setState({
        navComponents : navComponents
    })
}
```

I believe it should be getting username from App. However, username is *always* an empty string(The initial state of App). I'm unsure as to why Navbar isn't updating once component is mounted in App.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your doing it wrong, isn't ur render function suppose to do the markup for a component, 
try like this should work fine.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}



render(){
    return (
            {this.props.username ? 
             <> 
              <p>Hello, {this.props.username}</p>
              <ul className="Navbar-item">
                <Link to="/signout" className="Navbar-link">Sign Out</Link>
             </ul>
             </>
             : 
            <ul className="Navbar-list">
                <li className="Navbar-item">
                    <Link to="/register" className="Navbar-link">Sign Up</Link>
                </li>
                <li className="Navbar-item">
                    <Link to="/login" className="Navbar-link">Log In</Link>
                </li>
            </ul>})
}
```

Comment: Worked fine. I'm not sure why I overlooked that, to be honest. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is very simple, because `componentDidMount` of `Navbar` only being fired once, before `username` has a value.

What's happening with the flow is as below

1. `App.js` `render` being invoked
2. `App.js` `componentDidMount` being invoked
3. `App.js` fire API call
4. `Navbar` `render` being invoked
5. `Navbar` `componentDidMount` being invoked
6. Result of Step 3 coming back

Now because `componentDidMount` of `Navbar` will only be fired once, hence you will always see `this.props.username` is empty there. One of the simplest solution is by to handle your logic at `componentDidUpdate` instead of `componentDidMount`

Comment: if u pass a state as prop to a component, when ever the state changes in parent component , its pass to the child component, n calls it render function, n rerenders it again.

Comment: @RiazLaskar: Of course. Which is the reason why I said the routing logic shouldn't be in `componentDidMount`